# What is this bastard sys admin or something like that

Tags: history

I've read some long time ago something about the stories of a sys admin complaining about their LUSERS

It was something like the  bastard sys admin or something like that.

Do you have a link from the original history?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the link.

What's the story ( history?? ) behind BOFH.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're thinking of the [Bastard Operator From Hell](http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh) (BOFH), and his sidekick the [Pimply Faced Youth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PFY) (PFY). Enjoy :)

Comment: beat me by 30 secs, nice job!

Comment: heh, came back with the edit for History on Wikipedia and thought I'd missed it! ;)

Comment: Ahhh exactly that one. I read about it about 10 yrs ago ( maybe less?? ) but I didn't quite understand it.  Thanks for the refresh

Answer (score 3):

YUP its BOFH and everything can be found here

http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/

and earlier stuff here

http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/earlier.html

Answer (score 3):

The BOFH on the register is very funny, but, the very early stuff is by far the best.

The full archives are on Simon's site here.

http://bofh.ntk.net/Bastard_Indexes.html

Comment: Fab! I never knew about the pre-archive. at least ntk is getting some use :)